# Error: AGGREGATE(15;7;RANGE;1) _supposed to ignore hidden rows for particular array range but it doesn't

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please find bellow one issue I am encountering with AGGREGATE function: I don't succeed to make formula ignoring hidden rows

Imput data:

column B (B3:B500) --> text strings in the format of next Example  : 
24 ± 6 (18...30) μm

Desired Output Data:

- by formula only (not by vba)
- in this range, search the values between the "..." and the close parenthesis (equivalent of 30 from our example)
- return max of all cells
- don't take into account hidden rows/filtered cells

My solution:

- isolate text between "..." and close parenthesis ")" using MID & FIND
- transform text to number (multiplying by *1)
- apply AGGREGATE(14;7;RANGE;1)

  - 14 = large (max)
  - 7  = ignore error and hidden cells

The encountered problem:

I don't succeed to make formula ignoring hidden rows (I always get the same result for max, event I manually hide the row with the max value)

FORMULA

```
=AGGREGATE(14;7;(MID(B3:B500;FIND("...";B3:B500)+3;FIND(")";B3:B500)-FIND("...";B3:B500)-3)*1);1)
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Use a helper column to extrat the number then use SUBTOTAL(); So say your helper column was column C you would use `=SUBTOTAL(104,C3:C500)`

Comment: Hello Scott, thank you for your solution focused on the result, it solved the problem indeed. But I am still wondering what is the problem with aggregate function: it was supposed to ignore hidden rows but it doesn't.

Comment: The aggregate would work with the new helper column: `= AGGREGATE(14,7,C3:C500)`

Comment: Neither the aggregate or the subtotal works with the string parse, that needs to be done prior to the formula.

Comment: I applied aggregate to helper column and it worked, as I said in my previous comment.  With your second post I have my answer to the other question, so case closed. Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your formula as such, but it may be failing because ... can be inserted as a single character … code 133 in which case your formula should be

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,(MID(B3:B500,FIND(CHAR(133),B3:B500)+1,FIND(")",B3:B500)-FIND(CHAR(133),B3:B500)-1)*1),1)
```

EDIT Scott is correct, you would have to use a helper column to ignore hidden rows.

See the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) where it says that AGGREGATE will not ignore hidden rows if they are part of a calculation.

Here is a comparison of the direct calculation hiding row 10 (which contains 60) with the calculation using a helper column.

[image]

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for your answer. I get the same error. Please try to hide row 10 in your file, the max value remain 60, although the formula shall return 50 (the biggest value < 60 visible in this case).

Comment: In the documentation of the AGGREGATE function is says Note: The function will not ignore hidden rows, nested subtotals or nested aggregates if the array argument includes a calculation, for example: =AGGREGATE(14,3,A1:A100*(A1:A100>0),1). I will add this to my answer.